# How can I disable Firefox's ssl / tls certificate

Tags: ssl, firefox

I am working on a project that captures and analyses my network flow. For HTTPS, I am redirecting all traffic to a "fake" site; this site decrypts them and encrypts them again before sending to the real destination.

However, this man in middle attack does not work easily because Firefox will check the certificate and block the website (I am using a self-signed certificate).

Since there are many websites that I need to monitor, is there any way I can disable the certificate checking feature of Firefox? Or can I import the certificate once and have all websites unblocked? I have full control of the operating system of the browser.

Comment: what do you mean "sending to the real destination"? I mean you could probably create your own trusted certificate authority and then sign the certs with that. But I don't understand what you are trying accomplish. Just redirect the traffic to a completly separate ip address? You would have to build your own CA, and your own DNS, but what is the point if the real site is never involved anyway?

Comment: If you are responcible for the real site and are trying to make sure its operating correctly, wireshark has the ability to decrypt encrypted traffic that has been captured if you provide the encryption key. It should be possible with firefoxes NSS crypto library to build a plugin to accomplish that

Comment: For example, I am accessing `stackoverflow.com`, but the traffic is actually redirected to, say `10.10.10.10:443`. `10.10.10.10` decrypts the data, analyses it, and encrypt the data again and send to `stackoverflow.com:443`.

Comment: I need some directions on accomplishing the tasks (like building a CA)

Comment: um honeslty the fact that you want to build a way to man in the middle sites you don't own is kind of sketchy. If you had said this was for a site you control it would be a different story but this is definitely malicious code. Just use wireshark to capture the traffic. Then build a simple plugin to output the symmetric encryption key then look at the traffic after. I see no reason why this doesn't meet your objective

Comment: If you have access to the browser you can create a root CA certificate, add that to the browser, and use the root CA key to sign certificates for any domain you like.  You can generate a root key just like any other key, and self sign it.  There are many potential security risks associated with this practice - including the possibility of losing the key for the CA cert and opening your entire organisation to MiTM attacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the best way to solve my problem is automatically signing a website certificate. I followed [this tutorial](https://jamielinux.com/docs/openssl-certificate-authority/index.html) and some techniques like [Wildcard certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_certificate). After importing the certificate to Firefox, it trusts all the traffic.